# Python-Selenium browser-based login popup

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to create an automated login for a website trough python + selenium + chromedriver.
I saw tutorials on logging into embedded login elements using the element inspect etc, but this doesnt work here, since the login window is a popup and can't be inspected.

The popout from the browser I want to get my data in:
[image: popout]

Comment: What makes you think you cannot inspect that? Can you share the URL?

Answer (score 0):

On the image provided this looks to me like this is an htaccess 'popup'.

If so, you could put password and username in the url like:

`https://username:password@my-awesome-url.com`